# Asynchronous pageloads - How do you pass parameters to callbacks?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

Part of the jQuery/ajax asynchronous callback stuff still has me baffled, and I'm sure it's just because I don’t know javascript well enough.

Simplifying the code down as much as possible, this is where I'm stuck:

If I create an empty div with an id of "queuediv1" I can fill it with the results of a page method like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST", 
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
      dataType: "json", 
      url: "test12.aspx/GetHtmlTest", 
      //data: "{ 'Dividend': '" + $("#Dividend").val() + "' }", 
      data: "{}", 
      // Error! 
      error: function(xhr, status, error) { 
          // Boil the ASP.NET AJAX error down to JSON. 
          //var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")"); 

          // Display the specific error raised by the server 
          //alert(err.Message); 
          alert("AJAX Error!"); 
      }, 
       success: function(msg) { 
        $("#queuediv1").removeClass('isequeue_updating'); 
        $("#queuediv1").html(msg); 
            //an unorderd list with the tag "browserxx" was just inserted into the div 
        $("#browserxx").treeview(); 
      } 
    }); 
});
```

This works great; it doesn't the block, and it gives me full control of error handling. 
However, when I try to expand this, I get into trouble. If I have several areas of the page that I want to update, I can alter the call so that each async call is made with the correct "data", but I can't tell the callback the id of the control that I want it to populate.

Simplifying my case down to something that is still broken:

Suppose there are 4 divs in the DOM that with id's queuediv1,queuediv2,queuediv3, and queuediv4 that I want to update. 
I would like to reuse as much code as possible. 
While the number and id's of divs to be updated will actually be dynamic, I thought this would have worked:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
for (i= 1;i<=4;i++) 
{ 
     var divname ="#queuediv"+i; 

    $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST", 
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
      dataType: "json", 
      url: "test12.aspx/GetHtmlTest", 
      // data would be populated differently so that each div gets its own result- for now it doesn't matter 
      //data: "{ 'Dividend': '" + $("#Dividend").val() + "' }", 
      data: "{}", 
      // Error! 
      error: function(xhr, status, error) { 
          // Boil the ASP.NET AJAX error down to JSON. 
          //var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")"); 

          // Display the specific error raised by the server 
          //alert(err.Message); 
          alert("AJAX Error!"); 
      }, 
       success: function(msg) { 
        $(divname).removeClass('isequeue_updating'); 
        $(divname).html(msg); 
        $("#somethingfromthemsg").treeview(); 
      } 
    }); 
} 
});
```

But this can't ever work since by the time success is called the scope is wrong and the divname already equals "#queuediv4" for every callback. Only that div gets updated (4x).  Is there a way to pass a variable to the callback? Or am I just thinking about the problem wrong.

I did find something like this dealing with async calls to $.getJSON here: http://thefrontiergroup.com.au/blog/tag/jquery

This site talked about wrapping the callback inside another anonymous function to preserve the calling variables. That sort of made sense for scope but I have no idea how to form that the way the $.ajax call is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap every iteration of the for loop in an anonymous function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        (function () {
            var divname = "#queuediv" + i;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "test12.aspx/GetHtmlTest",
                data: "{}",
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("AJAX Error!");
                },
                success: function (msg) {
                    $(divname).removeClass('isequeue_updating');
                    $(divname).html(msg);
                    $("#somethingfromthemsg").treeview();
                }
            });
        })();
    }
});
```

A much simpler example would be:

```
<div id="output1"></div><div id="output2"></div><div id="output3"></div><div id="output4"></div><div id="output5"></div>
<script language="javascript">
    for (var a = 1; a <= 5; a++) {
        (function () {
            var divName = "output" + a;
            var b = a;
            setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML = b; }, 2000);
        })();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that JavaScript is a real functional language, and all functions (anonymous or not) are really full featured [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)), therefore variables from 'outside' a function are still available.

a generic method for solving the 'passing parameters' is the runtime construction of closures:

```
function makeSuccessFunc (divname) {
    return function (msg) {
        $(divname).removeClass('isequeue_updating'); 
        $(divname).html(msg); 
        $("#somethingfromthemsg").treeview(); 
    };
};
```

so you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
for (i= 1;i<=4;i++) 
{ 
     var divname ="#queuediv"+i; 

    $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST", 
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
      dataType: "json", 
      url: "test12.aspx/GetHtmlTest", 
      // data would be populated differently so that each div gets its own result- for now it doesn't matter 
      //data: "{ 'Dividend': '" + $("#Dividend").val() + "' }", 
      data: "{}", 
      // Error! 
      error: function(xhr, status, error) { 
          // Boil the ASP.NET AJAX error down to JSON. 
          //var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")"); 

          // Display the specific error raised by the server 
          //alert(err.Message); 
          alert("AJAX Error!"); 
      }, 
       success: makeSuccessFunc (divname)
    }); 
} 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Click.

Here are a couple good articles on closures as well that helped me:

JavaScript, time to grok closures

http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/23/javascript-time-to-grok-closures.aspx

Closures in C#

http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/derickbailey/archive/2009/02/23/closures-in-c-variable-scoping-and-value-types-vs-reference-types.aspx